# Node.js: bottlenecks when registering very large number of listeners and callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback, cluster-computing

I'm working on an application where a single server might receive as many as 100,000 requests for the results of the same, slow-executing (up to 5s) process. That means an `EventEmitter` with a crap-load of listeners and callbacks that will all be triggered at once. What kinds of things do I need to look out for here - is running out of memory an issue?

More implementation details, if that's relevant: going to use a cluster, with memcached to cache results and for locking (because only one request handler needs to work on each unique request at a time, while the other 99,999 wait for it to complete), with inter-process communication between the forks to trigger the necessary events across the cluster. So in reality we'll probably end up with 4 node processes each with 25,000 listeners waiting on some distributed event.

This seems to be the kind of thing that Node.js excels at, and I don't think there will be a [thundering herd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) issue, as each request isn't a process that will be woken, consume resources, and then all but one be put back to sleep again. Instead, when the event is triggered, all the other 99,999 requests will resolve one-by-one in an orderly fashion in the event loop on each node process.

I'm working on this now, so I'll post the results of stress tests as I go along, but figured I'd ask at the start what kind of bottlenecks we may run into here.

Comment: EventEmitter used to be limited to 10 events per name, so i think you might be stretching it a bit here. (https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/a4dad95be3e0051da7109aa016e9023ba714769b/lib/events.js) if the events don't repeat, i can't see the need for an eventemitter; it's a lot of overhead for tools you don't need.

Comment: You're right, though the limit can be set to 0 for unlimited. Not sure how else to go about this. This server may receive many thousands of requests per second for something that only needs to be calculated once but which takes several seconds to calculate (it involves HTTP requests), so there has to be thousands of callbacks registered *somewhere*. Would you suggest another way to register these?